# vlookup excel multiple sheets - fill empty cells

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm trying to do a vlookup formula but it just return N\A or #REF! all the time.
On one sheet I have the following columns: `sku, title, category, image url`
on the other sheet(let's call it update) I have: `sku, image url`.
I want to fill the blank image url on the first sheet(original) from the image url that I have on the other sheet(update).
I tried to do:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,update!A1:B1623,4,FALSE)
```

but it doesn't work. please help :)

Comment: Is it resolved now?

Answer (score 0):

In your formula your array reference is wrong. You mention `update` refence but it will be `original`. Try-

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,original!A1:B1623,4,FALSE)
```

Comment: it doesn't let me to choose the original for some reason